# Z-Transform on Dirac

Tags: signal-processing, z-transform

I have a question to do with doing a Z-Transform on a Dirac function for signal processing. 
So if we have $x(n)=\delta (n)+\delta (n-1)$
the transform should look like $X(z)=\sum (\delta (n)+\delta (n-1))z^{-n}$ with the sum going to infinity.

I would've thought solving this it would give me the answer $X(z)=1+z^{-1}$
However, the answer I have been given is $X(z)=1+z^{-n}$. I just don't understand why the $n$ is still in the equation after it has been summed.

[Here is the Z-Transform formula and x(n)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHDRc.png)

Comment: Your solution is correct. The answer should be $X(z) = 1 + z^{-1}$.

Comment: $1+z^{-N}$ is the Z-transform of $\delta(n)+\delta(n-N)$

Comment: @reuns but why?